# Foreach en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el resultado de la consulta ajax, recibo un json, a esto necesito listarle en un tabla, aplique lo siguiente, pero no me resulta. Alguien que me eche una mano, por favor.

```
    $.ajax({

    url:rutaOculta+"ajax/ajax.carrito.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:datos,
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(respuesta){

        var resultado=JSON.parse(respuesta);

        $.each(resultado, function(index, value) {
             $(".cuerpo-tabla").html('<tr>'+
                        '<th>'+inex.descripcion+'</th>'+
                        '<th>'+inex.precio+'</th>'+
                        '<th>'+inex.cantidad+'</th>'+
                    '</tr>');
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: oye tienes un error de escritura es index y mira pusiste inex @Capzzula

Comment: Parece que la sintaxis de la tabla esta mal, porque segun lo tienes solo estas poniendo th, cuando imagino que deben de ser td. Los th debes de ponerlos fuera, y usar el each para armar el resto de la tabla con el tr mas los td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintáxis para accerder a tus elementos deber ser primero a partir del objeto value que es el que te devolverá el valor de la posición y segundo en vez de acceder así : value.description  hazlo de este modo value['description']

Te anexo el siguiente ejemplo para que veas como hacerlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>PageName</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cuerpo-tabla">
    </tr>
  </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    var dato = [ 
     {"Id": 1, "PageName": "alfa"}, 
     {"Id": 2, "PageName": "beta"}, 
     {"Id": 3, "PageName": "gama"}
    ];



  $(function(){
    $.each(dato, function(index, value) {
             $(".cuerpo-tabla").html(
                        '<td>'+value['Id']+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+value['PageName']+'</td>');
        });
  })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O también puedes hacerlo con el método append y el método text del siguiente modo

```
 $.each(dato, function(index, value) {
             $(".cuerpo-tabla").append(
                        $('<td>').text(value.Id),
                        $('<td>').text(value.PageName));
        })
```

Comment: Tienes razón, lo cambie y sigue igual.¿Alguna otra alternativa ?

Comment: por favor agrega exactamente el error o el resultado que te esta dando @Capzzula

Comment: en console.log(index.descripcion); me resulta : undefined

Comment: @Capzzula le hice cambios espero sirva

Comment: Hola Alfredo, este es el json que recibo me parece que no es un formato correcto, me podrias ayudar con esto,                                     data {"id":"3","0":"3","descripcion":"Manga publicitaria modelo a5 - Rojo - S","1":"Manga publicitaria modelo a5 - Rojo - S","cantidad":"1","2":"1","precio":"50","3":"50","idpedido":"3","4":"3","idproducto":"37","5":"37"}                                                                
   desde php lo envio con un json_encode($respuesta);

Answer (score 1):

Puedes concatenar todo en una variable e imprimirlo en un elemento html, para acceder a los valores del json tienes que hacerlo desde "value" seguido del nombre del indice:

```js
var resultado=JSON.parse(respuesta);
var contenido = '';

$.each(resultado, function(index, value) {
    contenido += '<tr>'+
       '<th>'+value.descripcion+'</th>'+
       '<th>'+value.precio+'</th>'+
       '<th>'+value.cantidad+'</th>'+
    '</tr>';
});

$(".cuerpo-tabla").html(contenido);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los principales problemas es la función `.html()` que lo que hace es cargarse todo lo que hubiese antes en la tabla, por lo que siempre que escribes un nuevo registro, borra lo que hubiese antes, la solución a eso sería por ejemplo :

```
var html = "";
    $.each(resultado, function(index, value) {
               html+='<tr>'+
                            '<th>'+inex.descripcion+'</th>'+
                            '<th>'+inex.precio+'</th>'+
                            '<th>'+inex.cantidad+'</th>'+
                        '</tr>'
            });
 $(".cuerpo-tabla").html(html);
```

Otro error es que dentro del `<tr>` defines `<th>`, que son utilizados para encabezados, eso no origina un fallo de ejecución, pero sería más correcto utilizar `<td>`